# What happens with the thread that calls notify

Tags: java, multithreading

When a thread calls `wait()` it is blocked and waits for some notify.

But I want to know what happens with a thread that calls `notify()`. The current thread is blocked, and returns its execution at the notify point ?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. It just signals that the monitor has been notified, then keeps executing. Why would you expect it to block? (Assuming that by "the current thread" you mean the one calling `notify`.)

Comment: `notify()` is a non-blocking call. It executes like any other "normal" line.

Comment: Thanks Jon and user3580294, that is what i want to know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nothing happens to the current thread that calls `notify()`, it continues to run until it's natural end.

The `wait()` and `notify()` methods must be called within a `synchronized` context. As soon as the `synchronized` block that contains the `notify()` call finishes, the lock is then available and the block containing the `wait()` call in another thread can then continue.

Calling notify simply moves the waiting thread back into the **runnable** thread pool. That thread can then continue as soon as the lock is available.

Comment: And when a thread calls wait() and then the same thread comes back to run, the point of execution will be the wait() point, correct ?

Comment: Thanks Rudi ! It helps me a lot

Comment: And I think 'waiting' thread has a priority over 'blocked' thread in terms of order of execution when the notifier thread finishes it's critical section, right?

Answer (score 2):

Notify doesn't put current thread to sleep, only wakes up other threads that have waited on the same mutex

Notify doesn't block the executing thread and both the notifier and the waiter happily execute concurrently after that. Notify notifies one of the waiters at random, if you have more than one thread waiting and you want to wake them all you need to use notifyAll. Note that as all thread will still be in a critical section they will be marked active but will exit the critical block one at a time.

Notify doesn't block even if there are no waiting threads.

Note that this only represent the state of the thread: both threads will be active but actual dispatching of instruction depends: if you have more thread than cpu one of them will wait for its timeslice on the cpu.

Comment: `notifyAll()` has to be called to notify **all** waiting threads. A simple call to `notify()` wont do that.

Comment: And when a thread calls wait() and then the same thread comes back to run, the point of execution will be the wait() point, correct ?

Comment: Fixed notifyAll debacle thanks. Yes they will start from returning from the wait but, as the wait had happened in a synchronized block, they will have to wait for that synchronized object lock to be free exiting the block one at a time. http://booxs.biz/EN/java/Threads%20in%20Java.html in this fsm you can compare the two situations, waiting vs blocking.

Answer (score 0):

- wait() tells the calling thread to give up the monitor and go to sleep until some other thread enters the same monitor and calls notify( ).
- notify() wakes up the first thread that called wait() on the same object.

Under ideal condition notify() is called when thread completes its execution to go back again to calling thread. 
But if used before completion then the thread will continue its normal execution until reaches natural end.